# Questions regarding formatting glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

I recently started using `glossaries` package. Being a beginner in LaTeX, I came across a few problems and would like to ask questions. The code reads as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\newglossaryentry{fn}{type=symbols,name={$F_nF_nF_nF_nF_n$},sort=fn,
description={Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function}}
\newglossaryentry{fncon}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{F^{n^\ast}}},sort=fnc,
description={$n$-fold convolution of the distribution function/distribution $F$ convolution of the distribution function convolution of the distribution function convolution of the distribution function}}
\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\title{Latex World}
\author{James Brown}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\printglossaries

\newpage
\gls{fn}
\gls{fncon}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting nomenclature looks like as follows:
[image]

My questions are

1. I would like to remove the empty page created before the nomenclature.
2. I would like to right-align the symbols and for the multiple-lined description, the following lines to be horizontally aligned so that they start under which the first line of the description started.
3. I would like to group the symbols together and add a small bold-faced title on the first symbol of each group.
4. I would like to modify vertical spacing between symbols so that they are spaced the same as description lines. But would like to maintain the current spacing between groups.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could share any help as I am a total newbie to this and in the process of learning. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You should really ask one question at a time, i.e one per post. this is better for searching and usefulness

Comment: Have you looked at the various styles available described in the documentation? One of them is likely to be close to what you need and then you can work from there. Maybe one of the tqbular styles would suit you better than the default?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I would like to remove the empty page created before the nomenclature.

The empty page is caused by the empty `main` glossary when iterating over all the glossaries with `\printglossaries`. There are two solutions:

1. Use the package option `nomain` to prevent the automatic creation of the `main` glossary. (Only do this if you don't want this glossary.)
2. Use `\printglossary[type=symbols]`

> 2. I would like to right-align the symbols and for the multiple-lined
>      description, the following lines to be horizontally aligned so that
>      they start under which the first line of the description started.

The second part of this requirement can be obtained with the `altlist` style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}% always load after hyperref

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{fn}{type=symbols,name={$F_nF_nF_nF_nF_n$},sort=fn,
description={Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical
(sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution
function Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample)
distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function}}
\newglossaryentry{fncon}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{F^{n^\ast}}},sort=fnc,
description={$n$-fold convolution of the distribution
function/distribution $F$ convolution of the distribution function
convolution of the distribution function convolution of the
distribution function}}

\title{Latex World}
\author{James Brown}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\printglossary[type=symbols,style=altlist]

\newpage
\gls{fn}
\gls{fncon}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Right-aligning the symbol will look weird with this style as the wide symbol `$F_nF_nF_nF_nF_n$` extends over the description.

A better option might be to use the `alttree` style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}% always load after hyperref

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{fn}{type=symbols,name={$F_nF_nF_nF_nF_n$},sort=fn,
description={Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical
(sample) distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution
function Empirical (sample) distribution function Empirical (sample)
distribution function Empirical (sample) distribution function}}
\newglossaryentry{fncon}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{F^{n^\ast}}},sort=fnc,
description={$n$-fold convolution of the distribution
function/distribution $F$ convolution of the distribution function
convolution of the distribution function convolution of the
distribution function}}

\glssetwidest{$F_nF_nF_nF_nF_n$}
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamebox}[2]{%
  \makebox[#1][r]{#2~}%
}


\title{Latex World}
\author{James Brown}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\printglossary[type=symbols,style=alttree]

\newpage
\gls{fn}
\gls{fncon}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

> 3. I would like to group the symbols together and add a small bold-faced
>      title on the first symbol of each group.

This can be obtained by changing the style from `alttree` to `alttreegroup`.

[image: image of glossary]

> 4. I would like to modify vertical spacing between symbols so that they
>      are spaced the same as description lines. But would like to maintain
>      the current spacing between groups.

You don't have different groups in your example, but the tree styles are more compact than the list styles, so the `alttreegroup` style should fit this requirement.

You might want to have a look at [the gallery of all predefined styles](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/) and also [the more general gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/) for more ideas.